# Camera photo capture in Android 4.4 fails

Tags: android

I have following code for launching the camera app from my activity:

```
private Uri imageUri;
private void takeCameraPhoto() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "Pic.jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}
```

When user shoots photo and selects it, I get callback from Android in my onActivtyResult method which I have written like:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case TAKE_PICTURE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            tempView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

            try {
                imageBMP = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                     .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
            int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
            String newFilePath = selectedImage.toString().replace("file:///mnt/", "/");


            imageBMP = ShrinkBitmap(newFilePath, width, height);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBMP);
            Matrix m1= imageView.getImageMatrix();
            RectF drawableRect1 = new RectF(0, 0, imageBMP.getWidth(), imageBMP.getHeight());
            RectF viewRect1 = new RectF(0, 0, width - 50, height - 100);
            m1.setRectToRect(drawableRect1, viewRect1, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
            matrix.set(m1);
            imageBMP = null;
            System.gc();
            /*Toast.makeText(this, selectedImage.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
        }else{
            if (!isFromDialog) {
                PhotoDecorationActivity.this.finish();
            }

        }

        break;
```

In android 4.4 I get NullPointerException that imageBMP is null which is probably because of null newFilePath variable. What is the correct code for capturing image from camera and receiving it in my activity.Can someone help me pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
//This code is for launching the camera activity

    Integer cam = 0;
    Boolean gpicture;
    Intent action = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            startActivityForResult(action, cam);



//This is the code used to handle the request and display it on a bitmap

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

//process image gotten from gallery
                if (requestCode == cam && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                    gpicture = true;

                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    final String location = data.getDataString();

                    Bitmap bitmap = null;

                    try {
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    pic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
    }
```

This code is just used to get an image from the camera and display it on a bitmap,hope it helps you

Comment: what is Add_customer.RESULT_OK

Comment: sorry it's Activity.RESULT_OK....i'm editing my answer now...you can also use your activity name